# groovy closure inheritance

Tags: grails, groovy

How does inheritance work in groovy for closures?  Is there anything special to be aware of?  My application is to extend a plugin controller, that I need to leave alone should any updates come in for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closure inheritance doesn't make much sense (in the way we tend to use them anyway). A closure in practice is an instance of the `Closure` class. If we created subclasses of `Closure` then we could subclass those, but we don't. For example in controllers, we define actions as inline instances, e.g.

```
def list = {
...
}
```

These are treated like methods in that we can call `list()`, but that's just syntactic sugar for `list.call()`, since `call()` is an instance method of the `Closure` class.

In Grails 2.0 the preferred approach to creating controller actions is to use methods, although closures are still supported for backwards compatibility. One of the primary reasons for this switch is to support overloading and overriding, which isn't possible (or at least practical) with inline closures. You can define a closure instance in a subclass with the same name as a base class instance, but you can't call `super.list()` since it will result in a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: Burt - thanks for your reply and support.  I'm still integrating the Spring Security UI plugin and others, and may try to shoot a question your way as I'm digesting your answer and the various options.  Though looking forward to it, I'm currently assuming Grails 2 is not "for me" yet, as am building a soon to go live public facing web-site involving financial transactions / need for robustness and seeking to use various plugins (that may not work with 2.0??).  I really have no idea of that - just rough assumptions - still coming up the grails learning curve, so any comments/advice welcome.

Comment: 2.0 is quite stable, just be sure to check out the open issues that are marked to be fixed for 2.0 final. But you make a good point - some plugins haven't yet been updated. Most should work though, and testing will discover issues.